# Office Compatability Pack: no print in the context menu

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I am generating docx files in my application. I want to print them out (by calling shell execute with the verb "print").

It works on PCs with Office 2007 or 2010 and it works on one PC with the Office Compatability Pack installed - but on one of those it doesn't work.  Windows says that no application is linked with this file extensions.

I see that there is no entry "print" on the context menu for docx files on this computer. I wanted to update the Compability Pack, but it said it is already up to date.

Any ideas what could be wrong on this PC ?

Comment: Set the default program for the given extension.

Comment: Already did this - no change (but the problem is just on this special PC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to get printed by calling `"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office11\winword.exe" fileToPrint.docx /q /n /mFilePrintDefault /mFileExit`

It's not pretty - but at least it works. I just use it as a second strategy if ShellExecute with the print verb fails.